# foreign key referencing

Tags: sql

So the situation is this, currently constructing a university database.
I have an activity table that has an academic period column and I have another column called activity_enrolment that should refer to the academic period column from the activity table.

I've been trying to do the basic FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES activity(academic_period) but I am getting an error saying that "There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table".

Comment: So what's the question - have you added a primary key to the 'activity' table?

Comment: Is your design correct? If each activity has a single academic period, shouldn't enrolment reference the activity and then you can infer/join the period from the activity record? Why have a separate period column in the enrolment table?

Answer (score 0):

Mark the `academic_period` column of Activity table as Primary Key and then try.

Because to create Master and child relationship on a column between two tables, one column should have defined Primary key on that column.